# How do this XML code to CustomView constructor programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
**Guys i need help i am trying learn to **do** front-end work programmatically? How i should to do this XML layout in Custom View constructor? Thanks in advance! How i should make custom view constructor like this XML?**

    `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
     android:layout_margin="2dp">

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`

**Guys i need help i am trying learn to do front-end work programmatically? How i should to do this XML layout in Custom View constructor? Thanks in advance! How i should make custom view constructor like this XML?**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to build views programmatically, but you really should use XML. This way your applications behavior, logic (in the code) and the it's UI (in XML) are separated. Also, it's much faster to create layouts in XML.

Here is an example of using a custom view, it has one text view inside:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView textView;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
         super(context); 
         textView = new TextView(context);
         textView.setText("Hello");

         //we must use LayoutParams objects to manage layout properties programmatically
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          params.leftMargin = 5;
          params.rightMargin = 5;
          textView.setLayoutParams(params);

          addView(textView); //add to our layout
    }

}
```

I only added one text view, and set nothing but the side margins, but the code is already long, meanwhile you can do all this in XML as simply as this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the more complicated the layout gets, the better it is to create it in XML. Long story short, use XML for layouts, and inflate it in your code, instead of creating custom views.